# How is the NVIDIA RTX A6000 getting 300 watts via a single 8-pin?

Tags: nvidia, pci-e, motherboard

According to:
https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/design-visualization/quadro-product-literature/proviz-print-nvidia-rtx-a6000-datasheet-us-nvidia-1454980-r9-web%20(1).pdf

the NVIDIA RTX A6000 uses up to 300 watts of power. It has a single 8-pin CPU power connector and of course it connects via PCI-E. In spite of what was once stated, the PCI-E 4, to the best of my knowledge, still only supplies 75w. With the 8-pin supplying at most another 150w, my math says 225w. Other high powered cards use two 8-pins for this reason I believed. What's going on with the $5k card?

Comment: It's not using a regular PCIe auxilliary power 8-pin connector. It's using an EPS-12V 8-pin connector which is rated for 300W. See NVIDIA's application note "Power Guidelines for Workstation Products". The datasheet for the RTX A6000 refers to it as follows: Power connector 1x 8-pin CPU. Note the "CPU" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

njuffa's comment had the correct answer, but I cannot select a comment as correct.

An 8-pin CPU connector is different than an 8-pin auxiliary power connector.

https://www.pny.com/file%20library/company/support/product%20brochures/nvidia%20quadro/quadro-power-guidelines.pdf

In their power guide they show how to make an adapter for two 8 pin aux to an 8 pin CPU.